# Check if array is empty then return a result php

Tags: php, arrays, function

So i have an array who is generated based on a result and i must show a parametre if the other is empty so i used "empty" function to check.

First this is an exemple array :

```
{"expiration":"202302","cardholderName":"TEST TEST","depositAmount":0,"currency":"012","authCode":2,"params":{"respCode_desc":"Votre transaction a été rejetée, veuillez contacter votre banque.Code erreur :37","udf1":"2018105301346","respCode":"37"},"actionCode":203,"actionCodeDescription":"processing.error.203","ErrorCode":"3","ErrorMessage":"Order is not confirmed due to order’s state","OrderStatus":6,"OrderNumber":"11739","Pan":"628058**6618","Amount":102000,"Ip":"105.104.137.24","SvfeResponse":"37"}
```

i must return result of "actionCodeDescription" IF "respCode_desc" is empty so i wrote this :

```html
if ((function_exists( 'wc_add_notice'))  &&  ((empty($params->respCode_desc)))) {
                         
                        wc_add_notice( __($array->actionCodeDescription, 'wcwspay' ) . '! ' . __( '<img src="https://e-chrili.chedmed-svc.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/01/3020-1.png" ; />' ), $notice_type = 'error' );
                        
                        
                    }
                      else { wc_add_notice( __($params->respCode_desc, 'wcwspay' ) . '! ' . __( '<img src="" ; />' ), $notice_type = 'error' );
                    }
                
                    return $this->call_redirect( wc_get_checkout_url() );
                }
            
            
            
        }
    }
```

but it return always "actionCodeDescription" even when "respCode_desc" is not empty.
i'am doing something wrong and i dont know what is it.

Any idea for how to use empty properly?

Thank you

EDIT :

```html
$array =json_decode(wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response1 ));
                if(isset($array->approvalCode)){
                    $order_id = intval( $array->OrderNumber );
                    $order   = wc_get_order( $order_id );
                    $order->set_transaction_id($response['orderId']);
                    $order->add_meta_data('codeApp',$array->approvalCode,true);
                    $order->add_meta_data('Date',date("h:i:sa",strtotime('+1 hours')),true);
                    $this->logger->log( 'Payment for Order #' . $order->get_order_number() . ' completed.' );
                    $order->add_order_note( __( 'Payment completed via WSPay!', 'wcwspay' ) );
                    $order->payment_complete();
                    $woocommerce->cart->empty_cart();
                    $this->save_response_to_order( $response, $order );
                    return $this->call_redirect( $this->get_return_url( $order ) );
                }else{
                    $this->logger->log( 'WsPay response is invalid.', 'error' );
                    if ((function_exists( 'wc_add_notice'))  &&  ((empty($array->$params->respCode_desc)))) {
                         
                        wc_add_notice( __($array->actionCodeDescription, 'wcwspay' ) . '! ' . __( '<img src="https://e-chrili.chedmed-svc.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/01/3020-1.png" ; />' ), $notice_type = 'error' );
                        
                        
                    }
                      else if ((!empty($array->$params->respCode_desc))) { 
                          wc_add_notice( __($params->respCode_desc, 'wcwspay' ) . '! ' . __( '<img src="" ; />' ), $notice_type = 'error' );
                    }
                
                    return $this->call_redirect( wc_get_checkout_url() );
                }
            
            
            
        }
    }
```

FULL CODE

Comment: Can you paste full code?

Comment: I edited the post with the full code , thank you

Comment: Try checking this: empty($params->params)

Comment: @FilipKrzyżanowski thank you for your answer i tried but it is the same it always get actioncodedescription , i geuss he is not even checking

Answer (score 0):

It seems to look like  missing the object in to sub object check for value.
as per the array you post your condition missing the sub object to pass.

if ((function_exists( 'wc_add_notice'))  &&  ((empty($params->respCode_desc))))

you can change it to `if ((function_exists( 'wc_add_notice'))  &&  ((empty(($params->params->respCode_desc)))))`

here the screenshot of Array / Object print

[image]

you can force empty to validate the object-parame values by putting () around it. i.e. empty(($array->$params->respCode_desc))

Comment: @iegolbal you can try with this above change and suggest if that work

Comment: Thank you for your answer i changed it but it still the same , it always print actioncode description even if respcode_desc is NOT empty

Comment: @iegolbal just updated the answer you can try with that this part of code you can changes with and see if that work "empty(($array->$params->respCode_desc))"

Comment: Thank you again , but it didint work i dont know why , i doubled check that respcode is not empty , and it still show actioncode description :(